# Master/Slave replication and fault tolerance

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using solr-7.6 version with Master/Slave config. Being a novice, I do have few question on the solr functionality:
1. What happens when Master will be down? Do i need to make Slave as Master manually or request will be automatically served through Slave. Let me know if any config is required to support this behavior.
2. Will Master be retaining the older data when it comes up?
3. In this time-period while my Slave was up and Master was down, if new indexing has been done, how the Master will replicate that index. As I don't want to lose the latest index done on Slave.
Please note i don't want to use SolrCloud as i am looking forward to upgrade only solr version as of now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about pure Solr functionality not necessarily related to Sitecore.

Comment: Master will be connected with CM and Slave generally accessible via Load Balancer to CD. From Master Solr, documents pushed to Solr Slave. For availability of Solr Master, you can also scale Solr Master with two instances.

Answer (score 1):

1. When the master is down the slaves should continue to service any queries but will not be able to update their index when attempting to poll the master as it will be unavailable.
2. Presumably when master comes back up, you'd carry out a full reindex to ensure it's up to date.
3. The slaves should be set to readonly and the indexing strategy on CD servers should be set to manual. Hence the slaves should never update except when they pull the latest changes from the Master node.